# How can I check for empty textfields and email, password regex before calling a function?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, textfield

I'm trying to check for empty textfields and email and password regex before calling my chkInternet function, but can't figure it out, tried nested if statement, and making individual if statements with an else calling the function but that didn't work either, this is what I got so far but I'm stuck:

```
@IBAction func RegisterBTN(_ sender: Any) {


    let userEmail = userEmailTxtField.text!
    let userPhone = phoneNumberTxtField.text!
    let password = passwordTxtField.text!
    let passConfirm = passConfirmTxtField.text!

    let emailValid = isValidEmailAddress(emailAddressString: userEmail)
    let passValid = isPasswordValid(passWordString: password)

    if userEmail.isEmpty{

        emailErrorImg.isHidden = false

    }

    if userPhone.isEmpty{

        phoneErrorImg.isHidden = false
    }


    if password.isEmpty{

        passwordErrorImg.isHidden = false
    }

    if passConfirm.isEmpty{

        passConfirmErrorImg.isHidden = false

    }
    if !emailValid {

        emailErrorImg.isHidden = false

    }

    if !passValid {

        passwordErrorImg.isHidden = false

    }

        ChkInternet()


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of these codes are inside any function with no return type, simply adding `return` will suffice

```
    if userEmail.isEmpty {
        emailErrorImg.isHidden = false
        return
    }

    if userPhone.isEmpty {     
        phoneErrorImg.isHidden = false
        return
    }


    if password.isEmpty {
        passwordErrorImg.isHidden = false
        return
    }

    if passConfirm.isEmpty {
        passConfirmErrorImg.isHidden = false
        return
    }

    if !emailValid {
        emailErrorImg.isHidden = false
        return
    }

    if !passValid {
        passwordErrorImg.isHidden = false
        return
    }

    ChkInternet()
}
```

What return does is that it ends the execution of code inside a function block, meaning if `return` is called any and all codes below it will not be called anymore, therefore not calling your `ChkInternet()` function

For email validation simply add an `extension` to `String`

```
extension String
    var isValidEmail: Bool {
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(self)
    }
}


// use case
if !someTextfield.text.isValidEmail {
    return // do nothing cause not valid
}
// working codes here


// or
let someString: String = "asdasdawdaw"
if !someString.text.isVaildEmail {
    return // do nothing cause not valid
}
// working codes here


// or
let someString: String = "asdasdawdaw"
guard someString.text.isValidEmail else {
    return // do nothing cause not valid
}
// working codes here
```

Comment: i got it working with the return type, thank you so much

Comment: Mark my answer as the correct and an Upvote is all I need as thanks mate :)

Comment: still can't Upvote until my rep is 15, but did mark it as right answer

Comment: Using `NSPredicate` for a simple regex match is ill-advised. Use the native regex methods on `String` instead.

Comment: @ZonilyJame Additionally, this is the perfect case for guard clauses, rather than regular if statements

Comment: @Alexander yeah I use guards on my code, it's just I matched this answer to his current code.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out decent solutions, but there's a simple way to remove a lot of code repetition here:

```
let fieldImagePairs = [
    (userEmailTxtField, emailErrorImg),
    (phoneNumberTxtField, phoneErrorImg),
    (passwordTxtField, passwordErrorImg),
    (passConfirmTxtField, passConfirmErrorImg)
]

for (textField, errorImage) in fieldImagePairs {
    guard textField.text?.isEmpty == false else {
        errorImage.isHidden = false
        return
    }
}

guard emailValid else {
    emailErrorImg.isHidden = false
    return
}

guard passValid else {
    passwordErrorImg.isHidden = false
    return
}

ChkInternet()
```

Answer (score -2):

i am using third party library to remove this headache. try this [SwiftValidator](https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator)